# Regex Patterns Efficiency

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering, what would be the most appropriate way to run multiple regex patterns on a huge text document stored as in a StringBuilder.

Currently the way I do it is just create a new instance of Regex and run each pattern individually which is no way near efficient, resource and time wise.

Text document average would be like 3k+ lines, and the number of patterns would be like 20+.

Code as requested:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[524288];
long readSoFar = 0;
using (System.IO.Stream stream = fileInfo1.OpenRead)
{
    while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
    {
        int read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        readSoFar += read;
        for (int bi = 0; bi < buffer.Length; bi++)
        {
            if (buffer[bi] == 0)
            {
                buffer[bi] = 63;
            }
        }
        result1.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read));
    }
}

Regex regx = new Regex("Pattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(LoadedFile.ToString());

foreach (Match match in matches)
{

}
```

(I basically gradually load the text document under a buffer -> wait until the whole file is loaded -> run the regex checks)

Comment: You can start by showing us the code that you have and explaining *clearly* where you think the inefficiencies lie.  Still, it's not a guarantee that this question will be on topic, as it may still be too broad.  If you have some working code, I'd suggest posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't post the code I am using because I found it was unnecessary since it's nothing special, but for sure, I will edit the main post.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27671823/1033684

Comment: "the way I do it is just create a new instance of Regex and run each pattern individually which is no way near efficient" - that's the interesting part that we'd like to see in your code excerpt, I guess.

Comment: @RobSedgwick It's not really about multiple patterns more than the following points:
I need to check each pattern whether it matched or not, because that will decide how the code will continue. Plus, since the file is really large, it would still take time.

Comment: You can't use Regex on a StringBuilder. It works on *strings*. A StringBuilder is used to *build* strings, not read them

Comment: @Karizan are you trying to build a parser? Even if you don't deciding which regex to use in response to a previous one *is* the job of a parser. What are you *actually* trying to do? Regular expressions may or may not be the correct way to do this

Comment: Did you match your reading with exist System.File.Read methods?I think your file reading is slow.

Comment: Assuming you want to parse a file with different line and record types, you can use multiple regular expressions to identify different lines and/or records. You have to *organize* them though so that they make sense. You can't just apply all of them in a loop. For example, you can create different *rules*/classes to match different record types. Each record definition/rule can have a single regex that detects whether it applies or not. If it does, the rest of the record's regexes are used

Comment: When you do that though, you'll realize that those record regexes are exactly what parsers rules do. A proper parser could be easier to build than building and grouping multiple regular expressions

Comment: In any case, please provide an example of the text file and the kind of parsing you want to perform.

Comment: That is why I didn't want to provide the code, since it will not really help. The problem is not with how the file is loaded and parsed, but on how to run Regex in a way so it would be fast. Kind of text file is decided by the user, but it is just like any other. Just a bunch of text. This is an example of a pattern, "http://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\?\/\.\:\;\'\,]*)?" - So yes, I do need Regex since I am extracting data from the text file, but since I have multiple of those, it is slow and resource consuming.